# Origins of the TimeoutException

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, java-6, timeoutexception

Are the:

- [`Future#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) ([`FutureTask#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29))
- [`ExecutorService.html#invokeAny`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

only methods that can throw a [`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Look at docs half way down the page: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/class-use/TimeoutException.html

Comment: I need it for Java 6 only, how did you get to that page?

Comment: haha, yeah sometimes the docs are easily readable, as in this case!